# How to resolve this segmentation fault?

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, indexoutofboundsexception, circular-list

I'm trying to write logic to a program , and when implemented I've got segmentation fault .Can someone suggest me the cause of this error.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--)
        {
            int n,m,s;
            scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&m,&s);
            int a[n],i,j=s;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            a[i]=0;
            int ind=0;
            while(m>0)
            {
                a[j]=a[j]+1;
                ind=j;
                if ((j+1)%n==0)
                j=1;
                else
                j=(j+1)%n;
                m=m-1;
            }
            printf("%d\n",ind);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The number to specify on array declaration in C is the number of elements, not the maximum index. Array indices in C starts from zero.

Therefore,

```
            int a[n],i,j=s;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            a[i]=0;
```

is bad because it writes something to out-of-range `a[n]`.

Allocate one more element to avoid out-of-range access if you want to use the elements from `a[1]`, not `a[0]`.